# The work is done

Tags: grammar, tense, past-participles

Can the phrase

> The work is done

mean that the work is in the process in any context? Or does it always mean that the process of doing the work is finished?

Answer (score 3):

> The work is being done

^ the work is in process

> The work is done

^ the work is complete / finished.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**done**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/done) adjective [after verb]

> If **something is done**, or you are done with it, **it is finished**, or you
>   have finished doing, using it, etc.

If it's done then it's finished. If the work is still in progress, it's not done yet.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that "the work is done" *always* means "completed".

A point for consideration is what "the work" actually refers to. For example, any job can be broken down into tasks, and "the work" could refer to the entire job or just a task. Work can also be *ongoing*, so you could just mean your work for the day, and it will begin again tomorrow. Another possibility is that your "work" was to set some other work in motion.

If by saying "the work is done", you were referring to a particular task that set some other "work" in motion, it may be clear to you and the person to whom you are speaking what you mean. Otherwise "the work is *being* done", or "*the work is in progress*" would indicate that it is ongoing.